# Why do I see a lot of games using Unreal engine when there are much better alternatives?

Tags: unreal, cryengine

I play games on my computer often and I see a lot of games using the **Unreal engine**. Can someone explain why do developers choose to use this engine? In my opinion there are much better alternatives. For example games running on the **cry engine** look way better and the engine itself is more optimized.

Comment: Why do people still try to solve their differences with violence?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I'm trying to lead you gently to the idea that it's a matter of opinion, and that there might not always be a rational reason behind a game using one tech. over another except someones emotions.

Comment: The question is not appropriate for the site either way. Which Tech is more useful and why is a matter of opinion. Why are there dozens of brands of cars, clothes etc.

Comment: The only thing you have to do is run a benchmark and it will turn out that cry engine is like 2 times faster on the same hardware than the unreal engine.

Answer (score 9):

The unreal engine, or more specifically the Unreal Development Kit (UDK) is a very versatile and user friendly engine. There is a big community involved with it and it has great documentation and support for it. Furthermore, everyone can use the complete engine for free until a good amount of cash is earned with your product, i believe that is $50.000 I'm not familiar with the cry engine but i'm pretty sure it is not as versatile. Other then that, you say the cry engine looks way better, i doubt that. Since UDK is so versatile you can write your own shaders for it, i have seen very beautiful shots from the UDK engine, though i never compared it with cry engine.

That being said, a developer should pick a platform that will work for his game. If you need all the optimization you can get don't pick an engine at all but write one in C++. That goes for all needs.